# Rails Forem: permissions for users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, forem

I use Forem in my app. How can I allow non-admin and non-moderator users create topics and reply other users' posts without admin moderation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a new migration and add

```
change_column :forem_posts, :forem_status, :string, :default => 'approved', :null => false
```

[Source](https://github.com/radar/forem/issues/289#issuecomment-8320164)